# C code to assembly language

Tags: c, assembly

i need need help with translating this C code to assembly language it looks simple but i had hard time translating it . (using basic instructions like: MOV, ADD, SUB, INC, DEC, NEG)

```
int k = 0, S = 0;
while (k <= 500)
{
  S += k;
  k += 5;
}
```

Comment: What kind of help do you need?  Which part of it are you having trouble with?  And also, which kind of assembly language?  ARM?  x86-64?  Do you have to keep the loop, or can you just move `5*500` into a register like any decent C compiler would?  If you posted your asm attempt as an [mcve], someone might help you debug it.

Comment: @PeterCordes that would be 25250 though, right?

Comment: Oh I missed that it was `S += k`, so it's actually summing the series.  But there's still a closed-form formula for that.  https://nzmaths.co.nz/gauss-trick-staff-seminar.  So the best answer is two mov-immediate instructions that put the two constants into two registers.

Comment: @harold Yes, `S = kmax * (kmax + 1) / 10`. No need for a loop, so much easier to code in assembly. That makes 25250 for kmax=500 if kmax is sure to be constant.

Comment: i just wanted to know what it looks like after translating it to assembly language using the basic instructions like MOV, ADD, SUB, INC, DEC, NEG.

Comment: So put your code on http://gcc.godbolt.org/ and look at the compiler output.  Or do it locally with an x86 C compiler on your desktop.  Since the result is a compile-time constant, a good compiler won't use anything other than `MOV eax, 25250`, though.

Answer (score 1):

```
    mov ax,0
    mov bx,0
z:
    add bx,ax
    add ax,5
    cmp ax,500
    jle z
```

Something like that

Comment: This is not a correct translation. What you've written is a **do while** loop. The OP's question is about a **while** loop!

Comment: @SepRoland it was a `while` loop that executes at least once though, so I'd probably give this full credit if I was grading this.

Comment: all r-values  are constants at first check